# Livepatch not working in 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, canonical-livepatch

In Software & Updates / Livepatch I get this notification "Livepatch requires an internet connection." with a disabled switch in front of it. I am online so internet connection is up & running.

Screenshot Software & Updates:
[image: screenshot Software & Updates]

I tried to enable Livepatch by clicking Learn more in the Livepatch tab, got a token from the [Canonical Livepatch Service](https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/?_ga=2.41589922.1037519677.1555780621-30061940.1555780621)  , entered that in terminal according to the code provided:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo canonical-livepatch enable [insert token here]
```

Then I get this error:

```
*2019/04/20 19:41:37 error executing enable: 
Livepatchd error: The platform Ubuntu 19.04 is not supported. exiting.*
```

Any idea what's going on here? I thought Livepatch [should be supported](https://www.howtogeek.com/411278/whats-new-in-ubuntu-19.04-disco-dingo-available-now/) in 19.04.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, it's asking about 19.04 and software and updates does imply it is supported.

Comment: @fosslinux In that case that should be bug with the Software & Updates GUI, needs to be reported if it's not already. There is nothing specific about 19.04, it's a matter of LTS vs non-LTS release.

Comment: @fosslinux It seems this discrepancy in GUI is also addressed: [as per this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135593/livepatch-not-working-in-19-04#comment1888994_1135594), *in Software & Updates/Livepatch it checks first and then says "Livepatch is not available for this release."*

Answer (score 8):

19.04 does not offer livepatch(?).

My 19.04 claims:

> Livepatch is not available for this release.

Maybe it was intended to work but they cancelled it (again as they did with 18.10).

An [Ubuntu One account](https://www.ubuntu.com/livepatch) is required. [And a token](https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/?_ga=2.45173601.410314538.1555782976-1880816069.1554400810). And since you have a token I'd assume it does not work (yet) for 19.04.

---

The wiki [Kernel Livepatch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch) only points to LTS so the websites that show what is new are probably wrong or got wrong information from Canonical.

> This is a collection of notes and FAQs for the Canonical Livepatch Service. That page has a general introduction, data sheet and the ability to sign up for the service.
>
> Kernel Version
>
> - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit x86 4.15 GA generic and lowlatency kernel variants only
> - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit x86 4.4 GA generic and lowlatency kernel variants only
> - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit x86 4.4 Hardware Enablement kernel only
>
> Additionally, network access to the Canonical Livepatch Service (https://livepatch.canonical.com:443) and the latest version of snapd (at least 2.15) are needed.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have a Ubuntu One account. It is required to get the token. Could very well be that Livepatch is not working for now.

Comment: It still doesn't work today on 19.04, but to be fair, in Software & Updates/Livepatch it checks first and then says "Livepatch is not available for this release."